# Найти записи со значением FIELD1, как в поле с максимальным FIELD2

Tags: sql, db2

Допустим, есть таблица с множеством полей. Так же в ней есть два поля `Operation` и `Time`. Нужно вывести все записи, где поле `Operation` совпадает с `Operation` из записи с максимальным значением  `Time`. Допустим, поле `Time` не имеет повторений. Можно ли это организовать средствами SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

думаю как то так

```
select * from tab t1
join (select Operation from tab where Time = (select max(Time) from tab)) t2 on t2.Operation =t1.Operation
```

где `tab` это имя вашей таблицы.